# MFP 8 - Spring JPA integration which can be used across multiple adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We need to create a scalable application with a single instance of DB connection used across adapters , possibly want to use Spring hibernate for the same - how can we use mfp v 8  to implement such a use case.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "use Spring hibernate for the same"? Do you mean you want 2 adapters to share the same spring context?

Comment: Yes would like to use the spring context to use common  service beans across adapters

Answer (score 0):

> would like to use the spring context to use common service beans across adapters

I do not believe you can use it *across adapters*, as each adapter lives in its own sandbox. You'll need to add it to each adapter separately as a maven dependency in its pom.xml file.